# Can't get a menu (or menu item) of a pop up button in Logic Pro X using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

so basically i want to write an AppleScript that launches a plugin in Logic Pro X, but even after clicking the pop up button, it can't reach the menu (therefore none of the menu items (plug-ins))
[this is the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOKEt.png)
here is what i have tried, i found where the "Audio FX" pop up button is and i can click it, but i want to know if there is any way to reach menu 1 of it? according to automator's watch-me-do it should be there but for some reason i can't get into the menu

```
tell application "Logic Pro X" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Logic Pro X"
        set frontmost to true
        tell (first window whose subrole is "AXStandardWindow")
            tell group "Audio FX" of group 1 of group 1 of list 1 of list 1 of group 2
                tell pop up button 1
                    click
                    click menu item 3 of menu 1
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

so the error that i get is this:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group \"Audio FX\" of group 1 of group 1 of list 1 of list 1 of group 2 of window 1 of process \"Logic Pro X\" whose subrole = \"AXStandardWindow\". Invalid index." number -1719
```

Comment: This may a race condition: i.e. the script is processing faster than the menu is opening. Try putting `delay .2` between the two `click` statements.

Comment: @kyle did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ted Wrigley 's comment about it may be an issue of race condition.  Something like this may work for you.

```
tell application "Logic Pro X" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Logic Pro X"
        set frontmost to true
        tell (first window whose subrole is "AXStandardWindow")
            tell group "Audio FX" of group 1 of group 1 of list 1 of list 1 of group 2
                repeat while not (exists of pop up button 1)
                    delay 0.1
                end repeat
                tell pop up button 1
                    click
                    repeat while not (exists of menu item 3 of menu 1)
                        delay 0.1
                    end repeat
                    click menu item 3 of menu 1
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: i have tried delays before, that's not the issue. the menu 1 of pop up button 1 is not accessible unfortunately. maybe using jxa will help(?) but i have no idea how to use that for ui controls. this has been driving me crazy for the past week :(